# How do you get the description of a CalendarEntry using the google-api-java-client API on Android?

Tags: android, calendar, google-api-java-client

I am using the Google APIs Client Library for Java on Android to retrieve public Google Calendar entries:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

I was able to get the Android Calendar example working:

http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html

I made a sample Android app that pulls public Google Calendars just fine.  The CalendarEntry class has 'title' an 'summary' fields.  In my testing, the 'title' field holds the name of the event and the 'summary' field holds the Where and When data stored on Google servers.

How do you get the entry description stored on Google servers (not just the entry name, when, and where)?

Comment: I have also been struggling with this sample provided by Google.  I don't have an answer for you, but since it seams as though you've gotten a bit farther than me, can you take a look at my question found here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403293/google-api-java-client-for-google-calendar-on-android-infinite-loop

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question but in the [Google Calendar Api](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html), you can use `event.getDescription()`, see [here](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/71c8e9b19946f57835aaceee8ed2561c7f76a6f6/apis/calendar/v3/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/Event.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response rior, but I am not using the Google Calendar API.  I am using the Google APIs Client Library; see my first link.